# Натяжение в 2d играх

Tags: c#, unity3d

Здравствуйте. интересует вопрос, как сделать перемещение 2d объектов с помощью перемещения пальца по экрану. Чем больше дельта, тем сильнее он полетит. Объект должен лететь в противоположном направлении от перемещения пальца.

Comment: Где-то я уже это видел... Злые птицы, кажется..

Comment: У вас тут целых три вопроса. Это не хорошо - оставьте что-то одно тут, а остальное можете задать отдельными вопросами. Чтобы было понятно: 1. Как перемещать объекты касанием экрана? 2. Как сделать полёт объекта с заданными параметрами (возможно вспоминаем физику и геометрию)? 3.  Как сделать полёт объекта зависимым от предварительного смещения?

Comment: @vp_arth они самые, а вообще много их уже развелось

Comment: 2. Как сделать полёт объекта с заданными параметрами

Comment: >>Как сделать полёт объекта с заданными параметрами<< Первое что приходит на ум - дать его RigidBody компоненту принудительный AddForce. Пробовали подобное?

Comment: Замечу, импульс можно передать как всему объекту RigidBody, так и послать весь импульс силы в конкретную точку (например, чтобы закрутить его, как это было бы в случае, если бы мы ткнули пальцем в конкретную часть запускаемого объекта)

Comment: Ну, и ещё момент - вектор оттягивания коллинеарен вектору импульса который надо приложить телу.